# What does ':' and '::' mean in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, definition

In the book I'm reading it says about ratios and proportions,

> If $a:b::c:d;$ then $ad=bc$, and $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$

What do ':' and '::' mean? Also, it is not stating the above as a definition.

Comment: I read it as follows:  "$a$ is to $b$ as $c$ is to $d$"; Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology)

Comment: Terrible notation, by the way. Much better $a:b=c:d$, since it's factually its meaning.

Comment: Not only is it terrible notation, it's horribly rare: I've never come across this symbol before this question!

Comment: @YiFan It may be rare now, but it was quite standard when I was in elementary school.

Comment: @amd indeed, and I suspect the only places one would see such notation now are in old texts or similarly obscure places. I would certainly recommend against using such notation especially since it brings no benefit over the much more common and understandable $a:b=c:d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a:b$ denotes the [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio) of $a$ to $b$.

$a∶b∷c∶d$ is a proportion, a statement expressing the equality of the two ratios $a:b$ and $c:d$.

In English, it is often expressed as follows:  $a$ is to $b$ as $c$ is to $d$.

Comment: So is $a:b::c:d$ the same as saying $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$?

Comment: equal quotients correspond to equal ratios